# getting a Cannot set property 'value' of null message when trying to change what's in an image tag

Tags: javascript

here is my code. it works when i replace ***$("defaultimage").value = imgStr;*** with a document.write statement, but I don't want to use a doc.write statement.  Any tips on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance - javascript noob.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ColorPerceptionTest.css">


</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <img src="Default.png" name="defaultimage">

        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Button1" onClick="getRandomImage(imagesArray)">
            <input type="button" value="Button2" onClick="()">
            <input type="button" value="Button3" onClick="()">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="()">
            <input type="button" value="Help" onClick="()">

        </form>

    </section>


    <script>
        var $ = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }


        var imagesArray = ["1.gif", "2.gif", "3.gif", "4.gif", "5.gif", "6.gif", "7.gif",
                            "8.gif", "9.gif", "10.gif", "11.gif", "12.gif", "13.gif",
                            "14.gif", "15.gif"];

        function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
            path = path || 'images/';  //gets the default path here
            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
            var img = imgAr[ num ];
            var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
            $("defaultimage").value = imgStr;
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: try `$("defaultimage").html( imgStr )` -- but that selector still looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. Right now using `$("defaultimage")` you're trying to select an elemnt `<defaultimage></defaultimg>` Try instead `$('img[name="defaultimage"]')`. This is targeting an img tag with the name attribute of 'defaultimage'.

Also if you want to change the `src` of the `img` tag you cannot do it like this. Try instead `$('img[name="defaultimage"]').attr('src',newsource)` where `newsource` is a variable containing the new source you would like the image tag to have.

Well, there are a lot of things wrong here. haha. Using a class or id on the image would make even more sense.

Give it a go with this information and let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: So I am now trying to add a timer so that the image changes every 5 seconds,  but it's not working. Will update the code when I get home.

Comment: hey UKXK, check out the javascript setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

your selector should be:

`$("image[name='name']")`

please read this article for further info:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Your `var $` is a `getElementById`, you should pass the id of the `img` element to it, instead of name. Change your `<img src="Default.png" name="defaultimage">` to `<img src="Default.png" id="defaultimage">`, it will work.